# Why I am receiving duplicate rows in following query , Table structure is attached

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to remove duplicate rows?

Query is->

```
 SELECT       ps.Project_Brief_Description ,mscd.Brief_Description, Tbl_MilestoneCategory_Master.MileStoneCategory_Name, ps.AR_No_Perm, ptm.ProjectType_Name, mscd.Project_Id, mscd.MilestoneCategory_ID, mscd.MilestoneSubCategory_Id, 
                         mscd.MeasurementUnit, mscd.TotalWorkMeasure, mscd.WorkMeasureCompletion, mscd.TaskStartDate, mscd.TaskEndDate, mscd.ActualStartDate, mscd.ActualEndDate, mscd.ReasonForDelay, 
                         ps.Project_Id AS Expr1, ps.Executor_Dept_Id, ps.ProjectType_ID,ps.Project_Id, mscd.MilestoneCategory_ID 
FROM            Tbl_Project_MilestoneSubCategoryDetails AS mscd INNER JOIN
                         Tbl_Project_Summary AS ps ON mscd.Project_Id = ps.Project_Id INNER JOIN
                         Tbl_Project_Budget AS pb ON ps.Project_Id = pb.Project_Id INNER JOIN
                         Tbl_ProjectType_Master AS ptm ON ps.ProjectType_ID = ptm.ProjectType_Id INNER JOIN
                         Tbl_MilestoneCategory_Master ON mscd.MilestoneCategory_ID = Tbl_MilestoneCategory_Master.MilestoneCategory_Id
```

DataBase Structure snapshot

[image: enter image desc ption here]

Kindly note that, table with alias mscd has no primary key

Comment: use distinct keyword after select

Comment: because some of the tables you join with have more than one record on their master table. Add sample data if you want better answers

Comment: I'd recommend reading this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query), over on meta, that explains the importance of including sample data, and how that increases your chances receiving a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select distinct row from Tbl_Project_MilestoneSubCategoryDetails- table

```
 SELECT distinct
   ps.Project_Brief_Description ,
   mscd.Brief_Description,
   Tbl_MilestoneCategory_Master.MileStoneCategory_Name,
   ps.AR_No_Perm,
  ptm.ProjectType_Name,
  mscd.Project_Id,
  mscd.MilestoneCategory_ID,
  mscd.MilestoneSubCategory_Id,
  mscd.MeasurementUnit,
  mscd.TotalWorkMeasure,
  mscd.WorkMeasureCompletion,
  mscd.TaskStartDate,
  mscd.TaskEndDate,
  mscd.ActualStartDate,
  mscd.ActualEndDate,
  mscd.ReasonForDelay,
   ps.Project_Id AS Expr1,
   ps.Executor_Dept_Id,
   ps.ProjectType_ID,
   ps.Project_Id,
   mscd.MilestoneCategory_ID
   FROM
 --First select distinct row from this table
  (SELECT distinct Brief_Description,
  Project_Id,
  MilestoneCategory_ID,
  MilestoneSubCategory_Id,
  MeasurementUnit,
  TotalWorkMeasure,
  WorkMeasureCompletion,
  TaskStartDate,
  TaskEndDate,
  ActualStartDate,
  ActualEndDate,
  ReasonForDelay,
  MilestoneCategory_ID
 from Tbl_Project_MilestoneSubCategoryDetails) AS mscd
 INNER JOIN Tbl_Project_Summary            AS ps
 ON
  mscd.Project_Id = ps.Project_Id
 INNER JOIN Tbl_Project_Budget AS pb
 ON
 ps.Project_Id = pb.Project_Id
INNER JOIN Tbl_ProjectType_Master AS ptm
ON
  ps.ProjectType_ID = ptm.ProjectType_Id
INNER JOIN Tbl_MilestoneCategory_Master
ON
  mscd.MilestoneCategory_ID = 
  Tbl_MilestoneCategory_Master.MilestoneCategory_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rank() here, and in the having clause you can only pick where rank =1.
This way you can exclude the duplicate rows.